# A word or phrase that describes I'm going with a girl for a serious relationship

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm seeking a word or phrase which implies in the last few days I have a girl, but she's not a friend and she's not a girlfriend yet, we go together in order to see the possibility of being together in a relationship.

In my language, we say something that its translation is: "We are **going out together** in the last couple of days".

What is the parallel word/s or phrase in English?

Comment: I think what you are trying to express with the phrase *in the last time* is "recently" or "lately" or "these days".

Comment: absolutely, these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express an uncommitted relationship you can say

> - We're just seeing each other / dating, but we're not serious (yet).
> - I'm seeing a new girl but it's nothing serious

If you include *yet* in the first sentence, then the listener will guess that you are romantically interested in this girl and want to take the relationship further. In other words, you are ready to be in a serious (committed)  relationship.  But *dating* and *being serious about someone* is a tricky and nebulous area of language.

> “**I’ve been seeing** this guy for four months now – **we’re dating** and see each other a couple of times a week. However, if anyone refers to me as his girlfriend in front of him, the colour drains from his face. When I asked him if we were **going out** properly he just said he ‘wasn’t there yet, and wasn’t even sure if he wanted a serious relationship.’
>
> *[Daily Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/sex/10190628/When-is-a-relationship-a-relationship.html)*

Answer (score 2):

*Going out* is OK for this (you don't need the *together*); so is *dating*. *Going out* is a bit more non-committal—it doesn't exclude an escalating relationship, but it doesn't specifically imply it either, while *dating* at least suggests a relationship something more than merely casual or friendly: you are exploring escalation.

Answer (score 1):

> Dating

might be the word you are looking for.

It means the very beginning of a relationship when two people are still finding out about each other and there is no commitment involved.  A person may date multiple people during the same time period (I refrain from saying "at the same time" since that may be taken the wrong way).

> They're just dating.
>   It's just a date.

One might even say

> first date
>   second date

to show how new the relationship is.